Apache Superset Query Timeout issues with 4.0.0
We have followed all the steps mentioned here : https://www.restack.io/docs/superset-knowledge-increase-sql-server-query-timeout-superset#clp2vm1d700c5zi0un4y66zdw and still having the timeout issues. We are using Superset 4.0.0 version. Anyone is able to get this working without timeout issues?
Tried going thru all docs and performing config steps..
Expectation - no timeouts
